# Is it possible to prevent a file from being deleted unless in safe mode?

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, files, delete

Is it possible to make a file only deletable when in safe mode on linux? Specifically I am using ubuntu 14.04 and I need to prevent a file from being deleted.

If this solution is not possible is there another way where it would be difficult for Sudoer's to remove the file?

The only solution I know of is using chattr +i/-i and it is too easy to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The problem you have is that if an admin would not be able to remove a file it would introduce a security risk: someone with malicious intent and access to the system would then be able to install a file on your system even the admin of that system could not remove. A disgruntled admin could have some real fun with that...

Besides `attr` (that can be easily changed by an admin) you can also start the file with a dot making it invisible for normal commands (`ls` would need the `-a` option) making it harder for uneducated people to find and delete it (It will not fool someone who knows that there is a secret file present on the system). Nothing that can prevent deleting the file.

But ...

One method that will work though is to mount the file on a read only encrypted partition. The encryption is needed so "root" can not remount it without knowing the password. Someone could still remove the file when that person is able to remount it writeable and it has no relation to the "only in safe mode" part of your question though. But this seems to be the most practical approach.

Ubuntu also supports [encrypted private directories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory) (package `ecrypt-utils` but there are similar tools like `cryptkeeper`). But it depends if you need the contents of the file to enforce something or if it is actually the deleting of it that is a concern. To use the file you will need to open the directory with your login and password; it is then also possible to remove the file (so when you are not behind the system you will need to unmount the private directory to prevent deleting; when you are behind the machine and need it you can mount it and unmount it when not needed; limiting the time frame someone can delete it).

---

I do have one problem with your question: in general you really should trust an administrator to not mess with files. If you can not trust that person remove his access and restrict his account to a normal account with some extra privileges. Making sure you are the only admin is a better and a lot easier method in preventing deletion of that file.

Comment: Nice!  I would just have said: no...

Comment: Not really; since you can get around it by booting into a safe mode, that allows the real admin to do what they need to while preventing a hacker who has compromised the system remotely from doing too much damage.  There has been a lot of work in the area of preventing even root from doing things that can harm the system, for example, SELinux and Apparmor.  I'm pretty sure you can use these to accomplish what the OP wants, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: @psusi selinux and apparmor are not going to stop an admin.

Comment: Like I said, they won't stop a real admin since they can boot the machine into an insecure mode when needed, but their whole point is that they can stop programs from doing things, even if they otherwise would be allowed to by virtue of their uid, and that includes root.  With a sufficiently locked down apparmor or selinux setup, even root can't do things like install a new kernel or format a disk, or as the OP asked, modify certain protected files.